# Identify difficult parameter to measure

Tags: ranking, measurement-error, measurement, ranks

I am using different tools to measure x on some objects.  The tools were tested on a small set of objects for which the true x is known. And so the predicted values were found to not be accurate for some objects.
None of the three tools is 100% accurate. They accurately measure on some objects but not on some others. The problem: I want to know for which objects is it easy to accurately measure x and which ones are difficult in a larget set (than the test set). I don’t know the true x for any object.

What is the best way to proceed?

I have a table which contains the measure of x for each object for the set of tools. I am thinking about the rank variance across the different tools of an object. As the tools don't agree, this may indicate difficulty to capture x for that object.

Comment: if you don't know the true values for any object, how can you know that they accurately measure some objects, but not others?

Comment: The tools were tested on a small set of objects for which the true x is known. And so the predicted values were found to not be accurate for some objects.

Comment: Questions about Python (or any language) are off topic here. But if you delete the last sentence and add your comment to the question, then this can be reopened.

Comment: This is a measurement system problem and is more an engineering or physics question that statistics *per se*. Mind you, this pertains to data processing which is somewhat off topic here.